# Turn off runtime type checking in JVM

Tags: java, jvm

I am wondering if it is possible to turn off the run time type checking in JVM. I am doing a project of compiling from OCaml to Java Bytecode.

I hope to show if there could be any performance gain from doing all type checking at compile time (by OCaml type checker).

Comment: You can't.    It is cheap though.  You want to use generics if possible to let the compiler have the best working conditions.

Comment: What kind of run-time type checking are you talking about? And how is it supposed to work when turned off? Please show an example.

Answer (score 0):

After some reading on the actual Java Bytecodes I realised my problem is not exactly type checking. For the type checking part, Andersen's answer resolves the question.